# Reusing XIB views for collectionviews as a partial for other views?

Tags: swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, partial-views

I'm wanting to reuse one XIB file for collection views, and other views.

For example, I have a card that needs to be shown as a collection view cell, but I also would like to use the same xib/view for a standalone page.

ie;
[image: card image]

I would like to use the same card image for collection views and common views, almost like as if it were a partial; and can therefore use it wherever I need it.

I register my cell like this;

```
self.myCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCellIdentifier")
```

Then use it;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell:MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

...
}
```

I've tried to cast the dequeueReusableCell code with a UIView I created, but it doesn't like the view to be used in this way.

Both the cell and my XIB view file is a standalone swift file so its not in storyboard.

How can I use one uiview for collection views and then reuse the same view on other pages?

Many thanks

*Summary*

I want to use one UIView and XIB file in many places in the app

Currently, I have a collection view that uses a UICollectionViewCell and associated XIB file

I want to use the same XIB file in many places in the app.

How do I reuse the same UIView in both my collection view and the places in the app where I need it?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clear, you have a collectionViewCell and inside the cell you have a view that load a view form a nib, its correct?

Comment: (a) I have a swift file which I created; it a custom subclassed UICollectionViewCell.  It has a XIB file.  

(b) I want to reuse the same XIB elsewhere in the app, including all outlets and connections.

Comment: Can you show how it is?

Comment: I will try to eleborate more in my question

Comment: "How do I reuse the same UIView in both my collection view and the places in the app where I need it?" I guess my question is why you find this difficult. All you have to do is load the nib file and pull out the view each time you need a new copy of the "partial". Is the problem that you don't know how to do that?

Comment: Yes, this would be correct. I appreciate your help on this

Comment: Added some details to my answer below, but let me know if you need to me to elaborate even further or show you some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (a) I have a swift file which I created; it a custom subclassed UICollectionViewCell. It has a XIB file.

Register the nib with the collection view. In `cellForItemAt`, when you need a cell, dequeue it. You will receive a copy of the collection view cell from the nib. Configure it as desired. Return it.

> (b) I want to reuse the same XIB elsewhere in the app, including all outlets and connections

Load the nib and pull out the first (and only) top-level view. You will receive a copy of the collection view cell from the nib. Add it as a subview to a view in the interface.

(The easiest way to do that is through UINib and its `instantiate` method. This returns an array of the top-level objects.)

True, one does not usually use a collection view cell as a subview of an ordinary view. But I cannot think of any reason against it; after all, a view is a view is a view.

(If you would prefer not to do that, I can think of workarounds; for example, make the view in the nib a custom UIView and configure each cell by loading the nib and putting that view inside the cell. This will introduce some inconveniences, but it will make the nib more universally usable.)

---

I made a quick example. Here's the nib, very simple because it's only an example:

[image]

Here's my app, showing a collection view (showing four cells on a blue background) and also the view from the nib extracted and stuck into the interface:

[image]

Here's the *entire* code:

```
class MyView : UIView {
    @IBOutlet var iv : UIImageView?
}

class MyCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    var v : MyView?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var cv: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.cv.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let arr = UINib(nibName: "View", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)
        let v = arr[0] as! UIView
        self.view.addSubview(v)
        v.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:20, y:300)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        if cell.v == nil {
            let arr = UINib(nibName: "View", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)
            let v = arr[0] as! MyView
            cell.contentView.addSubview(v)
            cell.v = v
        }
        print(cell.v?.iv) // image view
        return cell
    }

}
```

Note the use of subclasses and outlets. `cell.v` takes us to the view, so `cell.v?.iv` takes us to the image view — and now we could perform further configuration, as desired. Thus we have one level of indirection added in order to reach a subview from the nib, but this seems a very small price to pay.

Comment: Yes, I would like to replace my current UICollectionViewCell with a standalone UIView with XIB; this same UIView would then be usable elsewhere.  I've been looking around github and other stackoverflow posts to see how others load views, and the code for this seems understandable

Comment: Dequeuing the cell is dequeuing the UICollectionViewCell; I tried replacing it wholesale with a simple UIView but it does not like UIViews being used as a `dequeueReusableCell`

Comment: I've seen examples where people load views through UINib instantate so I will try these.

Comment: If your top level object in the nib is not a UICollectionViewCell, you won't be able to fetch it as your cell by registering the nib. As I said in my suggested workaround above, you will have to register the UICollectionViewCell class, get the cell, load the nib, extract the view, and stuff it into the cell. But only if this cell is not a reused cell, of course. The downside is that your outlets will be outlets to the subview, not to the cell itself. But you can perhaps live with that.

Comment: Added a screen shot showing that this can work. I used the workaround described in my last paragraph, with the top-level object in the nib being a view, not a cell.

Comment: Just an update, following your code I was able to get it to work; I had to change a few things but am happy I got it to work and successfully used a UIView I created both in the collection view and elsewhere.  Thanks again

Comment: Yes, my goal was just to show you a general path forward. Glad you got it working! Thanks for reporting back.